# Cannot display using foreach_in_collection

Tags: foreach, tcl

I am trying to use [`foreach_in_collection`](http://quartushelp.altera.com/12.1/mergedProjects/tafs/tafs/tcl_pkg_misc_ver_1.0_cmd_foreach_in_collection.htm) to display a collection the code I am using is:

```
foreach_in_collection itr $outputs {
    puts [get_object_name[$itr]]
}
```

Here outputs is a collection which has values like `out1, out2 etc.` When I run this code I am getting an error like `unknown command '_sel843'`. I know to display he contents I have to convert it to list by using `get_object_name`. But it is not working. Please help.

Comment: Missing space at an important point, too much spaces at other points. `get_object_name_sel843` does probably not exist. add a space between `get_object`and `[$itr]`. I'm not sure if you have to call `$itr` to get the object.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

get_object_name is an internal procedure which accept an element of a collection.
You should use this value directly, instead of evaluating it.

The correct code is:

```
foreach_in_collection itr $outputs { puts [get_object_name $itr] }
```

Rgds,

Comment: Now when I am running the code:   foreach_in_collection itr $outputs {set out_pins [get_object_name $itr]  create_cell {[$out_pins]_OR} $library_name } only for out1 it is creating a cell but for out2 and out3 it is taking the value of out1 again and saying the cell is already created. Is the code wrong?

Comment: Before creating the cell, display it with a puts. You'll understand the problem with evaluation of [$out_pins]